# How to extract the boundy of the hole in pcl?

Tags: pcl

There is a point cloud on a plane with a circle hole,i wander how to extract the points of the hole to make me fit the 3D circle?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the `pcl::BoundaryEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::Boundary>` class. It is better to project the point cloud to the xoy plane,not the plane using ransac to fit.

It's a little bit weird, i don't know how the class work in pcl, isn't it using PCA method to calculate the boundary?Hope someone can give a explanation.

Use the plane fitted by ransac method to project(the boundary):

[image]

Use the XOY plane to project(the boundary):

[image]

Or use `pcl::ConcaveHullpcl::PointXYZ` class，which can also solve such problem.